# Spacing between table and textbox in reportviewer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I have 2 tables linked to data sets in my reportviewer. Below the right hand table is a series of text boxes (Paint materials etc). -

[image]

When the report is rendered, there is a big white space between the right hand table and the text boxes. How can I resolve this? I have set the property ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true and this does not seem to help.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contain the right table and the texboxes below it in a **Rectangle** to keep them together.

If objects are contained within a Rectangle, these will be rendered first relative to each other, then the overall Rectangle result will be rendered against the left table.

What's happening in your example is that SSRS sees the two tables are the same size, and assumes they should be rendered together, so it will move everything below the right table to the lowest point of the two tables. Forcing the right table and textboxes together with a Rectangle will prevent this.